# How to exclude files in Find()

Tags: regex, perl

I am using perl to find some kml files in a directory. The files are located in 
/Data/######/.
Where ###### is a 6 digit number.
All of the kmls are the same 6 digit number of whatever folder it was in ...
/Data/######/######_REP.kml

The problem is I have another folder 
/Data/QC/######/
with the same kmls in it as well. I want to ignore anything thats in that QC folder from my search.

My Code:

```
    sub repmatch{
    Push(@filelist,$File::Find::name) if ($File::Find::name =~ m\d{6}\/\d{6}_REP.kml$/)
    }

    find(\&repmatch,$dir) # $dir is my directory I passed in
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the repmatch subroutine, add (before push):

```
if ( $_ eq 'QC' ) {
    $File::Find::prune = 1;
    return;
}
```

That should solve it.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, forgot that long version is with path.

Comment: That Change made it work, Now if I had a QC2 or QC3 folder this wouldn't work, How could I append a * on it. Meaning if QC is anywhere in the string?

Comment: @user758114, `if (/^QC/) {`

Comment: if QC can be anywhere in the dir name: `if ( /QC/ ) {`

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want in at least two ways.

### Filter by complete path

On each invocation of your callback, the scalar `$File::Find::name` contains the complete path. The immediate parent of a file you want must be a 6-digit number, and the file must be the same number plus the suffix.

That looks like this.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

my $dir = @ARGV ? shift : "/Data";

my @filelist;
sub repmatch {
  push @filelist, $File::Find::name
    if $File::Find::name =~ m!/(\d{6})/\1_REP.kml$!;
}

find \&repmatch, $dir;

print "$_\n" for @filelist;
```

### Prune directories you want to ignore

Setting `$File::Find::prune` in your callback removes the current subtree from consideration in the remainder of the search.

Pruning allows your filter to be simpler. In each invocation of your callback, `$_` contains the name of the file, and anything that survives to this point can be tested against the digits-followed-by-suffix pattern. You could use the test from the previous program if you want to lock down the constraint on the name of the immediate parent.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

my $dir = @ARGV ? shift : "/Data";

my @filelist;
sub repmatch {
  $File::Find::prune = 1 if /^QC/ && -d;
  push @filelist, $File::Find::name
    if /^\d{6}_REP.kml$/;
}

find \&repmatch, $dir;

print "$_\n" for @filelist;
```

### Sample output

Given a directory structure of

```
$ ls -R Data
Data:
123456  654321  QC

Data/123456:
123456_REP.kml

Data/654321:
654321_REP.kml

Data/QC:
123456_REP.kml  654321_REP.kml
```

running either of the above programs produces the following output.

```
$ ./find-kml Data
Data/123456/123456_REP.kml
Data/654321/654321_REP.kml
```